# $(...).jqGrid is not a function in .aspx webpage

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I have a JQgrid that i am able to load into my Visual Studio 2010.But as per my requirement i need to add this JQgrid into my Visual Studio 2010 web project.On adding this to VS2013 i am getting following error..

```
$(...).jqGrid is not a function
empty string passed to getElementById
```

Here is the references that i have used ..

```
<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="plugins/ui.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="plugins/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue..

And this is the HTML..

```
              <div class="panel-body">
              <table id="UsersGrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              </table>
              <div id="UsersGridPager">
              </div>
              </div>
```

And here is the Full Script..

```
script type="text/javascript">
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    {

    var i=1;
    $('#Button1').click(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();

                if (i == 1) { getdata(); }
                else {
                    jQuery("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('GridUnload');
                    getdata();
                }
                i++; 


    });

    }
});

        function getdata() {
        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid({
            url: 'fetchdata.ashx',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype:'GET',
            height: 250,
            colNames: ['AccountNumber', 'BillNumber', 'BillDate'],
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'AccountNumber', index: 'AccountNumber', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center', hidden: true },
                    { name: 'BillNumber', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'BillDate', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },

                ],
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [100, 200, 300],
            pager: '#UsersGridPager',
            sortname: 'AccountNumber',
            viewrecords: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            sortorder: 'asc',
            autowidth: true,
            toppager: true,
            height: '100%'

        });

        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#UsersGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false });


    };

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.JqGrid` is definitively wrong. You should use `.jqGrid` instead. JavaScript is case sensitive.

**UPDATED**: Your code contains object with two properties with the name `height`: `height: 250` and `height:"100%"`. It's your error. You should remove `height: 250` to fix your error.

Moreover you should add `gridview: true` in your code. You can additionally use `$("#UsersGrid").jqGrid("GridUnload");` *before* the grid is created. The code of all methods test for `grid` property (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.custom.js#L75) of code) and if ´´ is not yet converted to the grid the call just do nothing. So you can remove all strange `i` variables from your code remove unneeded *global* function `getdata` and just move the body of `getdata` function inside of `$('#Button1').click` event handler.

One more remark: you should remove trailing comma (`,`) before `]` and reduce the definition of `colModel`

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'AccountNumber', index: 'AccountNumber', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center', hidden: true },
    { name: 'BillNumber', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
    { name: 'BillDate', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
]
```

to the following

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'AccountNumber', hidden: true },
    { name: 'BillNumber' },
    { name: 'BillDate' }
],
cmTemplate: {width: 100, align: 'center'}
```

By the way if you want to use `AccountNumber` as rowid then you should add `key: true` in the column definition.

Comment: Sir i have bootstrap files also in my webpage.Is it the reason because in my VS2010 solution they were not there..

Comment: @user3924730: What exactly error you have now and in what line of your or jqGrid code? By the way you should use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` before your code work correctly. Which version of jqGrid you use? Which HTML fragment you use in your code to initialize/create the jqGrid?

Comment: `jqGrid  4.1.2 - jQuery Grid `  This is the version and i tried with `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` still same error..I have updated my post with needed HTML fragement..

Comment: **What error** exactly you have now and **in which line** of your or jqGrid code?

Comment: Still in my console i have same error as `$(...).jqGrid is not a function`.Also i have some bootstrap.js files in my this project is it creating this issue?

Comment: **In which line** of your or jqGrid code you have the error? You can see the line in the Visual Studio 2010 debugger. Even if you start IE without debugging you press F12 to start Developer Tools, go to Script part and click Start debugging. You will see the laine with error, the exact call stack and to see the values of all variables.

Comment: The line `<div class="panel-body"` which you posted is not ended. Do you use `<div class="panel-body">`? By the way `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` attributes are not needed. The version `4.1.2` is more as 3 years old and I recommend you to go to 4.6.0 independent from your existing problem.

Comment: Do you want to find **the reason** of your existing problem? Then you should use the code which not work, just press F5 to debug it and see where you get the error which you posted in the question.

Comment: I am getting error at `height:100%` Also i have updated my post with my Grid and Script code >please have a look

Comment: @user3924730: Your code contains object with two properties with the name `height`: `height: 250` and `height:"100%"` (not `height:100%`). It's your error.